# How do I make a "global" <head> tag in VSCode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have a project that is ~25 HTML pages I've made "by hand"; this project is too small to have some sort of "site builder" to pull things from different sources and to build a page automatically/as-needed (that is also way out of my skillset, as you can probably tell by my lack of precise language).

I have Emmet abbreviations set up so I can type ! and it'll pre-populate the HTML file with custom things for this specific project, which is mostly content in the `<head>` tag. But sometimes I want to update what's in the `<head>` tag for *all* of my pages.

A recent example was adding Google Analytics tracking, which requires you to put 2 `<script>` tags in the `<head>` tag for every page in the site. So I manually copy/pasted it into each page.

I *feel* like there has to be a way where I update the `<head>` tag in one location and it'll be synced across all of my HTML pages. I *could* update the Emmet abbreviation template thing, but I would still have to go to every single page and update it. I have tried Googling this, looked here, looked at VSCode documentation and haven't seen anything. But I do feel like this has to exist, somehow, maybe in a VSCode extension somewhere or a project setting that I'm just not aware of and I don't know the right words to use to Google the answer myself.

Comment: *this project is too small to have some sort of "site builder" to pull things from different sources* — But you're trying to build some sort of site builder from scratch! Find one someone else wrote. https://jamstack.org/generators/

Comment: for small stuff you can use the **Find-Replace in Files**, second button in the Action Bar (magnify glass), find `</head>` and replace with `new stuff\n</head>`